# Get Name of Range in Excel with Formula

Tags: vba, excel

I've named a bunch of columns in Excel.

Now I would like to be able to get the name of a column in a cell using a formula.

So for example, if A:A was named Dates, I want to be able to put a formula in a cell such that =RangeName(A:A) returns the word Dates.

I've found examples of how to do this for a single cell, but not for a range of cells.

This is what I have found for a single cell.

```
    Public Function CellName(cel As Range) As Variant
Dim nm As Name
    For Each nm In Names
        If nm.RefersTo = "=" & cel.Parent.Name & "!" & cel.Address Then
            CellName = nm.Name
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
CellName = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a case for `Intersect`:

```
Public Function CellName(cel As Range) As Variant
    Dim nm As Name
    For Each nm In Names
        If Not Intersect(cel, nm.RefersToRange) Is Nothing Then
            CellName = nm.Name
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    CellName = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End Function
```

Comment: Ok - the logic makes sense to me, but it doesn't appear to be working. If I try and debug and step into the code, it gets to the If Not line for the first time, and then just ends without going through the For Each Loop or getting to the Exit Function

Comment: Try the function in a clean workbook with a limited set of named ranges. If that works, examine your first workbook for issues that could cause this. `On Error ...` and perhaps the Name Manager.